# Geometrical Complex Numbers Question - Equilateral Triangle

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried this problem but was unable to figure out how to do it, could I please get a hint.

Three points, of which $1+i \sqrt{3}$ is one point, lie on the circumference of a circle of radius 2 units and centre at the origin. If these three points form the three vertices of an equilateral triangle, find the other two points.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Rotate through $120$ degrees, that is, $2\pi/3$, and do it again.

Comment: How did you calculate 120 degrees? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Draw an equilateral triangle and its centre. Join the centre to the three   vertices; The three angles at the centre are $120$ degrees each, since they add up to $360$. The idea is also useful for general regular polygons, when we are calculating angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle to that point is 
$$ \theta_{1} = tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3} $$
The other two points must be separated by angles of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.  Knowing that, you can do some simple trig or polar coordinates with a radius of $2$ and angles of 
$
\frac{\pi}{3} \pm \frac{2\pi}{3}
$

[image]